# Can someone explain this matrix notation $A = [ A_1 A_2 A_3]$?

Tags: matrices, notation, block-matrices

Can someone explain this matrix notation $A = [ A_1 A_2 A_3]$?
For a matrix $A$, I know that $a_{12}$ or $A_{12}$ means row $1$, column $2$ in matrix $A$. However, what does $A_1$ refer to? For example, one reference noted this about a $3\times 3$ matrix like this: $A = [ A_1 A_2 A_3]$.

[image]

Comment: In that case each $\mathbf{A}_i$ is a column vector of dimension $3$. For example $$
{\bf A}_1  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{11} }  \\
   {a_{21} }  \\
   {a_{31} }  \\
\end{array}} \right]
$$

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought but I had to confirm. I appreciate the quick response too. :)